# Can I be paid for work I did outside the UK while visiting on a tourist visa?

Tags: usa, uk-visa, working, payment, uk-visitor-visa

I work remotely as a software developer, and am going to visit the UK for 6 months (just by showing my US passport upon entry for a tourist visa since I have never been to the UK before). I have housing accommodations arranged and sufficient finances for my stay there.

I won’t work while I am there (tourist visa requires that I do not), however

1. I have a few apps that provide me some income. Is it ok for me to receive that income as long as I don’t work on making any updates/bug fixes for these apps while in the UK?
2. Similarly, if I finish some remote work shortly before I leave, sometimes I won’t get paid for a month or so afterwards. Is it okay for me to receive that pay for work I did outside the UK?

Comment: Related, see second answer: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/45092/where-can-i-travel-for-prolonged-periods-of-time-while-legally-working-remotely

Comment: Do you mean receive that income in the UK?

Comment: What is the purpose of your visit? The 6 months is the length of the visa, but it is not intended for the residing in the UK.

Comment: @ouflak I am living with my long term partner for those 6 months, he is a student in the UK. You can see the edit history of this post for more info, I edited it out because it didn’t seem relevant

Comment: Then it sounds like you are residing in the UK and not 'visiting'. This is not what this visa (either through a waiver or otherwise) is at all intended for. It may not be relevant to you, but this is VERY relevant to the government of the United Kingdom.

Comment: @ouflak: so when does it cease to be visiting and turn into residence? Four months? Three? I think you need to substantiate your claim that it is not ok to stay with someone for six months on a UK tourist visa. I believe it is quite common.

Comment: @TomasBy, https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/87048/staying-full-six-months-using-uk-standard-visitor-visa. But common sense should really prevail here. Clearly the name of the visa alone should make it obvious that it is not for living in the UK. It is for short visits, perhaps even multiple short visits. One key point to **even qualify** for a visitor visa is to demonstrate that you have ties strong enough in your home country that you will return (such as a job which requires your presence, close family ties, business responsibilities, etc...).

Comment: @TomasBy, If you can leave your country for six months without even needing to go back (or anybody else requiring you to), this brings into serous doubt that you will actually return. The UK takes this into serious consideration as they have been taken advantage of time and time again at great cost. Again, I think this is just plain common sense. A visitor visa is for visiting, not residing. But if you want, look up the links. There are many discussion on the internet. Another: https://www.immigrationboards.com/general-uk-immigration-forum/u-k-6-months-visa-entry-rule-explanation-t217905.html

Comment: I left to the UK a few days ago and literally told the UK customs agent my plan to live with him for 6 months and he said it was fine, fwiw.

Answer (score 3):

Being paid while you are visiting on a tourist visa is fine.

For a simpler example, consider a full-time US employee that visits the UK for a week.  There is absolutely no problem about their employer depositing their salary in their bank account during the visit.

Comment: "depositing their salary in their bank account during the visit"  The employee's UK bank account?

Comment: @DJohnM I meant the employee's US bank account.  The OP will find it quite hard to open a bank account in the UK for a six month visit, and is vanishingly unlikely to give a US client a UK bank account to pay their bills to.

Comment: Yes I meant my US bank account, I don’t have a UK one

Comment: @MartinBonner do you have a source for this? What you say seems plausible but it would be nice to see it written somewhere

Comment: @MartinBonner, See the comments of the OP's post. Living with your long-time partner for 6 months in the UK on a visitor visa is NOT 'fine'. It is a violation of the UK immigration rules. That said, others have done it and not been caught, atleast not immediately. But their are exit checks in place now. It is not until they tried to return to the UK and the entry clearance system's red flags crept up. That always ends up in refused entry and can cause problems of any future entry (as the initial entry could be considered deception).

Comment: @ouflak I was answering the specific question "Can I be paid for work I did outside the UK while visiting on a tourist visa?" which *is* fine.  Living with your partner for six months is a different question.

Comment: @Phylliida - no I don't have a source for this.  I'm not sure anyone would bother to document it - it is just so obvious that a tourist visa covers the case that you are visiting when you happen to be paid.

Comment: @MartinBonner thanks, that makes sense. With regards to living there, potentially a relevant point is that my partner is a student for 9 months living under a Student Visa, and will be returning to the US after that. Both of our families are in the US, and he plans on attending grad school in the US after he completes his study in the UK. The Campus housing office is aware of me staying here on a tourist visa and ok’d it for the purpose of supporting my partner for those 6 months (cooking/cleaning/etc) while he is in school. This may be why they allowed it when they otherwise would not.